# Paint objects as class fields vs local variables

Tags: android, performance, rendering, paint

Should `Paint` objects be declared once as class fields or should they be created locally again and again on each call to the render method?

What's the most efficient and logical way of doing this?

Should they even be passed to dependent classes to avoid creating too many of them?

Basically, how heavy are `Paint` classes? Is it better to keep them in memory or to just use and throw away?

Thanks, people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of overhead when creating a Paint object, but the main thing you want to avoid is creating them on every draw() call since that may occur 60 times per second. Generally you should keep Paints around in class fields.